# Resizing window cannot be stopped when release mouse button

Tags: windows, winapi

```
LRESULT window_procedure(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_MOVE:
        {
            return 0;  // (1)
        }
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            ValidateRect(window, NULL); // (2)
            return 0;
        }
        }
    return DefWindowProcA(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}

while (TRUE)
{
    MSG message;
    BOOL result = PeekMessageA(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessageA(&message);
}
```

I have this piece of code and I found when I resize a window, the resizing grip is not released automatically when I release mouse button.

Some things that I tried that will get rid of this problem are:

1. Return `DefWindowProc` at (1)
2. Remove `ValidateRect` at (2)

Please enlighten me how any of these makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here:

```cpp
while (TRUE)
{
    MSG message;
    BOOL result = PeekMessageA(&message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessageA(&message);
}
```

The code continues to dispatch messages, even when `result` is `FALSE`. Either wrap the calls to `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` inside an `if (result)` condition, or properly initialize your variables (`MSG message{};`), or go with a more traditional message loop that calls `GetMessage` in place of `PeekMessage` (see [Using Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues)).

Comment: Ooops! That's very interesting. I had a printf in the window procedure before but it doesn't print anything when my mouse doesn't move. So I guess DispatchMessage somehow does internal filtering so that it doesn't call the window prcedure if the message type is not recognised.